# iOS7 Autolayout Issues - Adding UIView Subview to UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, constraints, autolayout

I have been trying for a few hours. I am adding a subclass of UIView to the view of my UITableViewController. I am using the code at the bottom of the this post.

I get a crash that says:

```
2014-06-15 12:19:58.724 Block Party[4712:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794
2014-06-15 12:19:58.726 Block Party[4712:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e940f0b 0x390d7ce7 0x2e940ddd 0x2f2ede2f 0x311703c5 0x30dec31b 0x30de7b3f 0x311854a1 0x3e387 0x311a5a3b 0x311bb8a5 0x3e221 0x3d267 0x31174a53 0x31174811 0x31300c13 0x3121e48f 0x3121e299 0x3121e231 0x31170305 0x30dec31b 0x30de7b3f 0x30de79d1 0x30de73e5 0x30de71f7 0x30de0f1d 0x2e90c039 0x2e9099c7 0x2e909d13 0x2e874769 0x2e87454b 0x337e16d3 0x311d3891 0x3acb5 0x395d5ab7) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I attempted to resolve this by adding the layoutSublayerofLayer method but it didn't change anything. Also, if I comment out [self.locationNeededView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; then it doesn't crash but my constraints are ignored because the autoresizingmaskconstraints take priority.

I'm totally out of ideas for how to solve this. Basically I want this view to appear on top of my table, centered horizontally and vertically.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

-Jeff

```
- (void) layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    [super layoutSublayersOfLayer:layer];
}
- (void)loadLocationNeededView {
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"LocationNeededUIView" bundle:nil];
    self.locationNeededView = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.locationNeededView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.locationNeededView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                    multiplier:0
                                                      constant:0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.locationNeededView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                    multiplier:0
                                                      constant:0]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.locationNeededView];
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}
```

---

**Edit - Update**

I gave up on using constraints and I'm just using the frame. I got it to work pretty well with the following code. I also found if I add it to the view of the navigation controller, then it won't scroll with the tableview. Which is exactly what I wanted.

```
- (void)loadLocationNeededView {
    //allocate subview
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"LocationNeededUIView" bundle:nil];
    self.locationNeededView = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    //set frame for it offscreen so it can be animated in
    self.locationNeededView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - (self.locationNeededView.frame.size.width / 2), [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, self.locationNeededView.frame.size.width, self.locationNeededView.frame.size.height);

    //addsubview to navigation controller so that it does not scroll with the tableview
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.locationNeededView];
    [self animateLocationNeededViewIn];
}

- (void) animateLocationNeededViewIn {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35
                          delay:1
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.7
          initialSpringVelocity:1.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^ {
                         self.locationNeededView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - (self.locationNeededView.frame.size.width / 2), (self.view.frame.size.height / 2) - (self.locationNeededView.frame.size.height / 2), self.locationNeededView.frame.size.width, self.locationNeededView.frame.size.height);
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];} completion:^ (BOOL fin) {
                             if (fin) {
                                 NSLog(@"After Animating View Frame: Origin X = %f. Origin Y = %f. Width = %f. Height = %f", self.locationNeededView.frame.origin.x, self.locationNeededView.frame.origin.y, self.locationNeededView.frame.size.width, self.locationNeededView.frame.size.height);
                             }
                         }];
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `[super layoutSubviews];` in the `layoutSubviews` method?

Comment: Do you want this view to scroll with the table? If not, you should use a UIViewController instead, because any view you add to a UITableViewController becomes a subview of the table.

Comment: In my UIView subclass' implementation i have declared 
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
Also, when I tried to present a modalviewcontroller it doesn't seem to support a clear background for the uiviewcontroller. It just blacks out and covers the screen the user was originally on. But I think I may try it again because I'm having so much trouble.

Comment: Your constraint multipliers are wrong. they should be 1. Basically, you made your views constrain to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Issues: Constraint Multipliers should be 1, not 0. also, you shouldn't need to call layoutSubviews, just call layoutIfNeeded. Also your view needs width and height constraints unless you have defined intrinsiccontentSize in your view.